# Standing water at bottom of sink

Tags: plumbing, drain, faucet, sink

I wish I could figure out how to load a picture that’s a small enough file to explain but hoping someone can understand what I’m saying here. I have a ring of water around the entire perimeter of the waste seat at the bottom of the sink bowl with new faucet/drain combo I have installed. I would think tightening it more (to bend the waste seat toward the center of the hole) may work but don’t its fairly tight and I’m a bit worried I could over tighten and have an instant regret. [image: drain]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If you upload your picture to an external site, and edit in the link, someone will be along to edit in the picture.

Comment: Is there a recessed area in sink bottom that the drain sits in?

Comment: No bending should occur in order for a drain to seat properly.

Comment: Ok I think I was just able to load the picture. And yes there is a recessed area in the bottom of the sink. It is sitting within the recess as well, not proud at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there's an answer to this, other than installing a slightly larger drain kit, or one that isn't so convex. Perhaps after cleaning it a few times with a scotch brite pad it will have less surface tension.